# react-bootstrap-table sorting does not work properly on number field

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-bootstrap-table

I have a project using ReactJS for front-end with Firebase Realtime Database. react-bootstrap-table is used in data listing. Sorting on the number fields does not work properly. I can't find any API/plugin to force change the data type of those fields.

> Default sort by: **Price - desc**

[image: Datatable]

> Sorted by: **Capacity - desc**

[image: Sorted by Capacity]

> JSON structure for an item

[image: JSON for an item]

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.posts} striped hover search pagination exportCSV options={ options }>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey dataAlign="center" hidden>Key</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="capacity" dataSort>Capacity</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="location" dataSort>Location</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataSort>Price</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="createdByLong" valueField="id" dataSort dataFormat={this.dateFormatter}>Created By</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old one but in case you haven't found a solution, this might help.

Looks like the sorting functionality is alphabetical by default.

To apply numeric sorting, try using [sortFunc](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#sortFunc) on the column you want to apply the numeric sorting and give a custom callback function to perform your numeric sorting.

For example, for the price, I added the numericSortFunc function like this:

```
function numericSortFunc(a, b, order) {
  if (order === 'desc') {
    return Number(b.price) - Number(a.price);
  } else {
    return Number(a.price) - Number(b.price);
  }
}

<BootstrapTable data={this.state.posts} striped hover search pagination exportCSV options={ options }>
  …
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataSort sortFunc={ numericSortFunc }>Price</TableHeaderColumn>
  …
</BootstrapTable>
```

Hope this makes sense!